# Java Proxy - Can't receive response from host/Socket issue

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, bufferedreader

I am coding a simple Java proxy. The general architecture was given to me (method signatures etc), and this is how the Main class looks:

```
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static ServerSocket client;
private static int myPort;

public static void init(int port) throws IOException {
    client = new ServerSocket(port);
    clientSocket = client.accept();
}
public static void handle(Socket clientSocket) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(in);

        String hostname = httpRequest.getHost();
        //443 hardcoded from reading the http headers. 
        //Testing using isitchristmas.com
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostname, 443);
        BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(out);
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        myPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try {
            System.out.println("Initializing socket...");
            init(myPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR]: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        handle(clientSocket);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("[ERROR]: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However the console hangs and never completes a request when reading in `HttpResponse` class:

```
    public HttpResponse(BufferedReader fromServer) throws IOException {
    String line;
    String statusLine = "";
    // Never goes past here
    while ((line = fromServer.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }

        if (line.toLowerCase().contains("status")) {
            statusLine = line;
        }

        response.append(line);
    }

    if (!response.toString().isEmpty()) {
        getDataAndHeadersFromResponse(response.toString());
        System.out.println("\n\nHTTP Response:\n");
        System.out.println("Status Line: " + statusLine);
        System.out.println("Header Lines: " + headerLines + "\n\n");
        System.out.println("Data: " + data);
    }

}
```

I suspect it has something to do with how I am creating the sockets... not calling `close()` on `ServerSocket` gives off a Address already in use: JVM_Bind exception. I also don't seem to get the serverSocket parameters right. As you can tell by now I'm not very versed in socket programming. What is wrong here?

Comment: Almost everything is wrong. If you're going to implement HTTP proxying you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616, especially the parts about content length. You're trying to read HTTPS with a plaintext Socket. Your general architecture is already wrong to use a`Reader.` A `ServerSocket` is not a 'client'. You need a new thread per accepted connection, and a loop that accepts them. Etc etc etc.

Comment: Apparently it shouldn't be that complicated. This is the exercise. It's not for me, but I'm helping out a friend: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=86822892327719350011

Comment: A terrible assignment. A class called `ProxyCache` that doesn't cache anything but that listens for and accepts requests? An HTTP proxy that uses `BufferedReader`? Why a `BufferedReader` to read from the client and a `DataInputStream` to read from the server? Nothing mentioned about content-length? It's not even how you write a real proxy. Students should complain. There's not enough information provided here and some of the code structure is positively useless. In the meantime one of you should have a good look at the Custom Networking section of the Oracle Java Tutorial. Too broad.

Comment: NB The basic problem is insoluble without a knowledge of content-length, and without knowing that the line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Comment: Other than that those static fields made me cringe

Comment: Ah, I thought so... I have handled HTTP requests before but not in Java. In php you do need to know content-length... should have figured that out. No way to fix this as it is?

Comment: Certainly: you have to read the Content-length header from both client and server and read exactly that many *bytes* of the request/response body after the blank line ending the headers. This is why a `BufferedReader` is completely out of court.

Comment: Well... I'll give him the bad news. On the other hand this was a great opportunity to "learn"(?) some socket programming in Java. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to listen on port 80: nothing in the assignment about HTTPS.
- The request body won't be terminated by end of stream, because the client still has the socket open to read the response.
- You need to read the Content-length header from the client and then read exactly that many bytes of request body.
- You therefore cannot solve this problem with a `BufferedReader`, as you have to count bytes, not chars.
- Having sent the request on to the server, all you really need to do afterwards is copy the response bytes directly from the server to the client: *not* what it says in the assignment.
- To stick with what the assignment says, you would similarly have to read the Content-Length header from the server, and all the other headers, and the blank line, and exactly content-length bytes of response from the server, and copy them all to the client. You can see this is a waste of time compared to just copying bytes.
- The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not `\n`.

The assignment is deficient in:

- specifying the infeasible `BufferedReader`
- then inconsistently specifying `DataInputStream` for reading from the server
- there is no reason to use `DataInputStream` at all: `InputStream` would suffice
- not referring to RFC 2616 or its predecessors or successors
- not specifying whether HTTP 1.0 or 1.1
- not saying more about 'to cache Web pages', which is only mentioned on page 2 and never thereafter.

Students should complain.